# cypress record multiple url redirect after a click

Tags: cypress

I have a scenario where on clicking the submit button will redirect to /redirect1 page where we will be doing some validation and redirects automatically to /redirect2 and do some other validation and get redirects to the /success page.

I need to verify that on clicking submit button it moves to /redirect1 page and then to /redirect2 page and finally get landed to the /success page

How to automate this process using cypress

Comment: Interesting.  I will ponder on it. My first thought is if you get /success then you know it worked.. is there something on those pages that tell you, that you got to the page, some text, the title, etc.?

Comment: @Maccurt Nope...

Comment: Let me look deeper, I think there is a way you can say the url went to a certain page. I think that is possibly the answer, but I don't know the syntax, let me look deeper... I have never needed to do this, but I think it something I want to do in the future..

Comment: It seems like you need to use `cy.location()`, and since the redirects happen sequentially use the callback form of the command with each step nested within the previous callback. [Example](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location.html#No-Args)

Answer (score 2):

I like to be very specific about what I expect to happen so I usually do the following:

**Arrange:**

1. Specify the API endpoints you are about to call / need to wait for (this is not necessary but you can be sure the assertions won't run until the call resolves)

   ```
   cy.server()
   cy.route('POST', '**/registration').as('registerCall')
   cy.route('POST', '**/verification').as('verifyCall')
   ```

   (you can match the route by exact String, Glob or RegEx, https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax)

**Act:**

2. Hit it off

   ```
   cy.visit('/')
     .getByText('Start the process')
     .click()
   ```

**Assert:**

3. a) If you expect it to immediately redirect, assert for it

   ```
   cy.url().should('eq', `${BASE_URL}/redirect1`)
   ```

*or*

3. b) If you are making the API call and redirecting only after that, let's wait for it to resolve and then assert. We specify the API call we're waiting for with the `@` followed by the alias we set above (`cy.route(...).as(yourAlias)`). I aliased my first API call as `registerCall` so we wait for that to resolve before making further assertions:

   ```
   cy.wait('@registerCall')

   cy.url().should('eq', `${BASE_URL}/redirect1`)
   ```
4. If you expect some text/loader to show up, check for it

   ```
   cy.findByTestId('loader-component').should('be.visible')
   cy.getByText(/^please wait$/i).should('be.visible')
   ```
5. Wait for the next API call, and check for route change after it

   ```
   cy.wait('@verifyCall')

   cy.url().should('eq', `${BASE_URL}/redirect2`)
   ```
6. ... chain the rest of you assertions. This can go on forever.

Hope this helps, let me know if I made some things unclear!

P.S. the `getByText` (along with other cool selectors) comes from the [cypress-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cypress-testing-library) which is built on top of the [dom-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/dom-testing-library) and allows you to do navigate your application as a user would, i.e. mainly just by finding text.

Comment: `BASE_URL` is not defined if you specify it as [baseUrl in cypress.json](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Global)

Comment: @vladkras sorry for not mentioning, the `BASE_URL` here is just a local variable. How you construct your URL strings is completely up to you, but the flow remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the URL(s) you could possibly do something like this

```
cy.url().should('include', '/redirect1');
cy.url().should('include', '/redirect2');
cy.url().should('include', '/success');
```

I am assuming it will try those and wait until they happen..